# Convert from Infix Notation to Prefix Notation

Tags: code-golf, math

Given an arithmetic expression, which can include parentheses (`()`), exponents (`^`), division (`/`) and multiplication (`*`), addition (`+`) and subtraction (`-`) (in that order of operation), such as

```
a ^ (2 / 3) * 9 * 3 - 4 * 6
```

output the same expression in prefix notation.

```
(- (* (* (^ a (/ 2 3)) 9) 3) (* 4 6))
```

Spaces are optional in the input as well as the output. You may assume that all operators are left-associative and that all of the numbers in the expression are single digit integers (i.e. `[0-9]`).

This is a code golf challenge, so the shortest solution wins.

Comment: Are + and - the same precedence, or is + higher than -?  I.e., is `3+4-5+6 = (((3+4)-5)+6)` or `((3+4)-(5+6))`?

Comment: Also, you left out division in your list of operations.

Comment: are parentheses optional in output?

Comment: @KeithRandall `*` and `/` have the same precedence, as do `+` amd `-`.

Comment: @Gajet No, they're not.

Answer (score 13):

### Ruby 1.9 - 134

```
%w[** / * + -].map{|o|String.send(:define_method,o){|n|"(#{o=='**'??^:o} #{self} #{n})"}}
puts eval gets.gsub(/\w/,'?\0').gsub ?^,'**'
```

Pretty evil, but it works:

```
$ echo 'a ^ (2 / 3) * 9 * 3 - 4 * 6' | ruby sol.rb
(- (* (* (^ a (/ 2 3)) 9) 3) (* 4 6))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 222 chars

```
class A:
 def __init__(s,x):s.v=x
for x in('pow^','mul*','div/','add+','sub-'):exec('A.__'+x[:3]+'__=lambda s,y:A("('+x[3]+'"+s.v+y.v+")")')
import re
print eval(re.sub('(\\w)','A("\\1")',raw_input().replace('^','**'))).v
```

Similar to the Ruby one, except Python doesn't let you redefine the global ops, only ops of a class.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6 (146|150)

The easiest way to do this is to just swap out the subroutines that implement the operators for new ones.

```perl6
sub infix:«+»   ($a,$b) { "(+ $a $b)" }
sub infix:«-»   ($a,$b) { "(- $a $b)" }
sub infix:«*»   ($a,$b) { "(* $a $b)" }
sub infix:['/'] ($a,$b) { "(/ $a $b)" } # stupid highlighter
sub infix:«**»  ($a,$b) { "(^ $a $b)" }

# currently there seems to be a bug that
# prevents this from modifying the parser correctly
# probably because there is already a different operator with this name
# which has nothing to do with exponentiation
my &infix:«^» := &[**];

say 'a' ** (2 / 3) * 9 * 3 - 4 * 6;
# (- (* (* (^ a (/ 2 3)) 9) 3) (* 4 6))␤
```

The absolute minimum amount of bytes for doing it this way is:

```perl6
sub infix:<+>{"(+ $^a $^b)"}␤  #   29
sub infix:<->{"(- $^a $^b)"}␤  # + 29
sub infix:<*>{"(* $^a $^b)"}␤  # + 29
sub infix:<**>{"(^ $^a $^b)"}␤ # + 30
sub infix:</>{"(/ $^a $^b)"}␤  # + 29
```

146 bytes, although it makes more sense to count graphemes in Perl 6.

This assumes that "*output the same expression in prefix notation*" could just refer to the result of the expression, not necessarily the output of the program.

You would have to add `say`  in front of the expression to get the program to print it to STDOUT. (150 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

### [Unix TMG](https://github.com/amakukha/tmg), 189 bytes

```
p:ignore(<< >>)parse(e);e:q(t,a);t:q(x,m);x:q(r,h);q:proc(x,y)x k:y/d x={<(>2 3 1<)>}b\k;r:o(!<<+-*/^()>>)|<(>e<)>;a:o(<<+->>);m:o(<<*/>>);h:o(<<^>>);o:proc(n)smark any(n)scopy;d:;b:bundle;
```

The solution is almost straight from the [manual](https://amakukha.github.io/tmg/TMG_Manual_McIlroy_1972.html) for the language, with only basic golfing.

Expanded:

```
prog:  ignore(<< >>) parse(expr);
expr:  q(term, addop);
term:  q(fact, mulop);
fact:  q(prim, expop);
q:     proc(x,y) x k: y/done x ={ <(> 2 3 1 <)> } b\k;
prim:  op(!<<+-*/^()>>) | <(> expr <)>;
addop: op(<<+->>);
mulop: op(<<*/>>);
expop: op(<<^>>);
op:    proc(n) smark any(n) scopy;
done:  ;
b:     bundle;
```