# Add parentheses to Polish notation

Tags: code-golf, string

In most programming languages, arithmetic is written with *infix notation* -- i.e. the operator is put in between the operands -- e.g. `1+2`. In contrast, with **Polish notation** (a.k.a *prefix notation*), the operator comes *before* the operands -- e.g. `+1 2`. As long as the number of operands for each operator is fixed, this means that parentheses are never necessary, unlike with infix notation.

### The Challenge

Given a string consisting of nonnegative integers (digits 0 through 9), spaces, `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` representing a single expression in Polish notation, add parentheses around each sub-expression, maintaining the whitespace. The parentheses should start right before the operator and end right after the last operands. You can assume each function has arity 2 (i.e. it takes in exactly 2 operands). You can also assume there will be no extra preceding zeros (e.g. `000` or `09`).

### Test Cases

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `+1 2` | `(+1 2)` |
| `++ 1 2 3` | `(+(+ 1 2) 3)` |
| `+1 +2 3` | `(+1 (+2 3))` |
| `* *1 2 /3 0` | `(* (*1 2) (/3 0))` |
| `//30 300/18 205` | `(/(/30 300)(/18 205))` |
| `/ -20/ 30 30 999` | `(/ (-20(/ 30 30)) 999)` |
| `/////1 2 3 4 5 6` | `(/(/(/(/(/1 2) 3) 4) 5) 6)` |
| `/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 9` | `(/1(/2(/3(/4(/5(/6(/7(/8 9))))))))` |

Standard loopholes are forbidden. As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest program wins.

Comment: Argh I was gonna post this about a month ago but never got around to doing it :P

Comment: @Seggan It's been in the Sandbox for almost a week, so you can't say you were scooped :P

Comment: Suggested test case: `/20/30 30/18 205`

Comment: @mousetail That's not a valid expression.

Comment: Also the last test case seems incorrect, there shouldn't be a space between the `/` and `30` right?

Comment: Sorry, what about `//30 30/18 205`

Comment: Point of this test case is testing the case where a closing parenthesis is immediately followed by a opening parenthesis

Comment: @mousetail Added.

Comment: Can we assume whitespace will be space characters (ASCII 32), or do we have to handle other whitespace characters like tab, newline, vertical tab, etc.?

Comment: @DLosc I originally intended all whitespace, but I think that it's more interesting if limited to spaces only, so I'll say that.

Comment: *maintaining the whitespace* - this seems unnecessary and prevents answers from parsing languages like `flex`.

Comment: Can we assume the numbers are all integers? The challenge only states that they are nonnegative, not explicitly that they are integers (although the test cases heavily imply it).

Comment: Suggested test case: `/////1 2 3 4 5 6` – a regex 4 bytes shorter passes all the current test cases but [breaks on this one](https://tinyurl.com/mwjrdv4j "PHP – Try It Online"). And I'd also suggest `/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 9` because this pattern approaches the maximum ratio of {number of parentheses pairs added} / {string length}.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5847/convert-from-postfix-notation-to-infix-notation)

Answer (score 15):

## Regex (Perl / PCRE / Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup>), <s>48</s> <s>47</s> <s>45</s> <s>44</s> 43 bytes

```
s~([*-/]( *(\d++|\((?1)\))){2})(?!\))~($1)~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzbCoJQEEXfz1fsROJciDkXrcQuH5LRQwkKVmJBoOWvn47uh5m9FsO0ZdekPu73Ov9UdVPy3UEM1@p5b3OD2fjXyE9yRWcOyYubUt@C86MRhRBisD/Bj4tQRx4bMfo87pfLtqsf76h4RIH2JsfM8eXnlYFlSiEsOIaQYKY5oYScPDlogBE5Dac1mS2sThlhZTVhlkCWZeEiZP6EBCnWjAxZcpRQSmva0BbZHw) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVNhb5swEP3Or7giVNsJxJC0XVNCo0ptpUzbPqyrNinJEAGTsBJANlmjpslfz85E09Rp3YcigY/z@b13z/YsUov96PYuACmiBByZACEgBwMSvukhxmBYLSqwJARQSTEPpajyKBaU8E5rGIaLKK/DuFxWWS7khE6YP/nMFbGR1oYUk@Fc6IKiFkWtaBjejj7chCGzwWO@kaVALTl2p0cBUYRBvZDlIxTiEW7WsajqrCwo@ZgplRVzMJVJcI2VoBRc5E19aNYnl2RH4Pn5oG8Z1fEC1Y1dp3/lTKaRs7Uoa7U7g8vh9ykntpWwfxOZo@JnlGcJJCLPllktpKnpdOdiXeVlIpDLRmp2II7LVVGjfHYUnLyC@FWWKLxYLWdCQpn@QVYNtDp00sVOrPQQ93SsKbHNzqFNPSaYnWM2jXIlfCMtcXuxTVXLUFV5hjJSBpECK2abxpQYjo8Bp6tSUXOeLdX66vr@2/uVaWNJEAQN0CuG3xdSxOW8yJ5EAmkeofWkY8Udov0/eB4HAZkTZs2DWq6EDwLRtO4OCo/9rZEVWahETc0qlqIzi@KHWuInbNo3bTAdz9RYL8qQdSUVSvh/2Y/DlKstRCOo9RS4vpUHKZ40Re@@XI8@MZ9tUCi18jF6kIsCI@Z40yAwJ4XJsFitZjiDadu1Ha9pC4GYiBelLkG7nwLPNwA0g49wVhW8OP@WxKOg8M1tcDxbO9@AHGEww915QIhc72Plb0HDgmnlpr/968pQ5u/Vjo5bDp9SaNFJ0m4/TygdemzCGNt0t4wOjzDcUctju/3brrHRCHAK1LCRFxeOtzUvYzzQHbzbvliLGPhKST7LCq5v@@@pfduDrtFuAw7QQzMAMKO/@rcFLZ3nPXABDM57LvRcl3vn0HVPDQ5O1@XQJAH6/T5W4NMgwQmcwpnBPd7lPX7CT/kZf8fPof8L) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVNhb5swEP3Or7giq9gJxJC0XSPqRpPaSZ22fdhWbVLIEAFDWAkgm6xV2@SvZ2fyYeq0Dsn4OJ/fvfds2lW7v5i1qxaIAgGtkkWsZFslqaQOHw1mcbxKqi5Om3VbVlJFNGJh9JlrxwUHR47JuJCmoO5k3Wkax@9uPlzHMXMhYKFV5kCJmvuLI@Foh0G3Us091PIerh9S2XZlU1PnY6l1WRdga9vBPSRDKrgpWITQ788unZ0Dz88HfuukS1fIbu5707detEi8LaFsMBxdXM5@LLjjkoz9u5F9U/9KqjKDTFbluuyksk07o1w@tFWTSezlYmt2aJw2m7pD@uxInLyC@E01SLzerJdSQZP/QdY9tD4oGaMSkh/iiYlNS5Q5Osg0c4bZArN5UmkZWnmjZIIydadi3VYl0sgZJBpIyp56U1I4PgZcbhtN7aJc64e3V7ff329sF0uEED3QK4bf1kqmTVGXjzKDvErQemdE0pFj/D94ngrhFA4jhejURoYgEc3wHiHxNNxaZV3GWnbUblMlR8skvesUvuJevu2C7QW2wXpRhl03SiOF/5f9PCz5xkI0gpJH4YekEjneNE2/fL26@cRC9oREKanm6EEla4yYFyyEsKPaZlisN0tcwbTru17Qy0IgJtNVY0rQ7kcRhBaA6RAiHGnFi/tPFF4FjaNywQtc43wPcoTBEk/nDiEqc45tuAUDCzap7HD71y9DWbjXOzofeHxBYUCjbDh8jiidBSxijD2Nt4zOjjDcURKw3X4/DGBsDYeAE0yQHwBmzNt8DmBg8nwCPoDF@cSHie/z4BzG/qnFwRv7HPokwHQ6xQp8eiQ4gVM4s3jAx3zCT/gpP@Nv@DlMfwM) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJdb9owFH3Pr7iNJsWGFOcDKIR5VbehCYkWqe22h8CkdHGoNcdBdthKv/46uwmrqknNQ2If3XvuOfdks6tvKx3vZbmpTA12Z30j1uJuAoYb13X39pmknWO2ItAhy7zbfVwSchrSJaX0IXqi5PQIj89kGdLnPdanYXIcrhxZgEmD1RH3rJeAyaQVcLXTdXY3NaYyxDuX1kq9Bte6HnVybtJDV2VyklOQGqyoe1stK03wREym14L0R/5gRKn/ioxP/DAa/AcNB/44RuShU2YbgoS@@47QTrf3/sPpD5c@0TcFzfTvTMkccqFkKWthUJYBDqZnN0rWKKqRp4Qmhh7x/psc302FlvS2vBEGquKVyyJZobK15cEEflZbXfPQKSoDRePUpPEqcQDpC869NS7sUBI4IJQVCbSt8MjhwZNe0ubTm325WFxOP51dTX3wyhf0/Ov8ejafXTSgfQE/L67P5nNE7l6Qb9PLj4ur6VNarByLu49Wbd6YwQTucW4jTbUh7GzP1rnUB32NfUUh0zmoFHNGuUuNehVXadAGD39upRIQYj2UzfraeXZ7g3vzwfqg/IM7/@CKTnAQhxJ/FuzAEWXa0AYJ3BiR/Wqn3iewMVLXhDqoLpz8uwmdc0X33RAip9sF/ECMHACINO/m2oFOg7MYAgCHsTiAOAhYOIIoGDgMjqOAQQsCjMdjrMCnZYI@DGDosJBFLGZ9NmBDdsJGMP4L) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>

This is a single regex substitution to be repeatedly applied until it has nothing to match (or until there is no change, where necessary or convenient).

In the following explanation, `␣` represents a space:

```
s~         # Begin substitution - match the following:
(          # Define subroutine (?1); $1 = the following (the entire match):
    [*-/]  # Character class of the four arithmetic operators. This also
           # includes "," and ".", but those are guaranteed not to be in the
           # input.
    (
        ␣*        # Any number of spaces, minimum zero.
        (         # Define subroutine (?2) as an argument to an operator:
            \d++  # Any number of digit characters, minimum one; force all of
                  # them to be consumed (prevent backtracking).
        |  # or...
            \(    # An opening parenthesis
            (?1)  # Recursively call (?1)
            \)    # A closing parenthesis
        )
    ){2}   # Do the above twice (for two arguments).
)
(?!\))     # Assert there is no closing parenthesis following this, as that
           # would indicate that this expression has already been parenthesized.
~          # Replace with the following:
($1)       # Preserve $1 (the entire match), and surround it with parentheses.
~          # Flags:
           # No global flag. For better efficiency, adding the "g" flag
           # would allow the substitution loop to end sooner, but it's
           # not needed.
```

Saved 1 byte by using `{2}` instead of a subroutine call for the second argument (shamelessly stolen from [Neil's regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250879/17216)).

### Bonus: Convert Polish notation to infix notation, <s>58</s> 52 bytes

```
s~([*-/]) *(\d++|\((?2)(?1)(?2)\)) *((?2))~($2$1$3)~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVNhb5swEP3Or7giq9gJxJC0XSPqRpPaSZ22fdhWbVLIEAFDWAkgm6xV2@SvZ2fyYeq0Dsn4OJ/fe/ds2lW7v5i1qxaIAgGtkkWsZFslqaQOHw1mcbxKqi5Om3VbVlJFNGJh9JlrxwUHR47JuJCmoO5k3Wkax@9uPlzHMXMhYKFV5kCJmvuLI@Foh0G3Us091PIerh9S2XZlU1PnY6l1WRdga9vBPSRDKbgpWITQ788unZ0Dz88HfeukS1eobu5707detEi8LaFsMBxdXM5@LLjjkoz9m8i@qX8lVZlBJqtyXXZS2YbOdC4f2qrJJHK5SM0OxGmzqTuUz47EySuI31SDwuvNeikVNPkfZN1D60MnY@yE5Id4YmJDiW2ODm2aOcNsgdk8qbQMrbxRMsE2dadi3VYlysgZJBpIyp56U1I4PgZcbhtN7aJc64e3V7ff329sF0uEED3QK4bf1kqmTVGXjzKDvErQemdE0pFj/D94ngrhFA4jhejURoYgEc3oHqHwNNxaZV3GWnbUblMlR8skvesUvuK@fdsF2wtsg/WiDFk3SqOE/5f9PCz5xkI0gpJH4YekEjneNE2/fL26@cRC9oRCKanm6EEla4yYFyyEsKPaZlisN0tcwbTru17Qt4VATKarxpSg3Y8iCC0AwxAiHGnFi/tPFF4FjaNywQtc43wPcoTBEk/nDiEqc45tuAUDCzap7HD71y9DWbjXOzofeHzBYECjbDh8jiidjRmdBczMETMLJmI7SsYkIBO22@@HAYyt4RBwggkKBcCMeZvPAQxMnk/AB7A4n/gw8X0enMPYP7U4eGOfQ58EmE6nWIFPjwQncApnFg/4mE/4CT/lZ/wNP4fpbw) - PCRE2

```
s~        # Begin substitution - match the following:
([*-/])   # Define subroutine (?1): Character class of the four arithmetic
          # operators. This also includes "," and ".", but those are guaranteed
          # not to be in the input.
␣*        # Any number of spaces, minimum zero.
(         # Define subroutine (?2) as an argument to an operator:
    \d++  # Any number of digit characters, minimum one; force all of
          # them to be consumed (prevent backtracking).
|  # or...
    \(    # An opening parenthesis
    (?2)  # An argument
    (?1)  # An operator
    (?2)  # An argument
    \)    # A closing parenthesis
)
␣*        # Any number of spaces, minimum zero.
(         # $3 = the following:
    (?2)  # second argument
)
          # No need for "(?!\))", because parenthesized expressions won't be in
          # ARGUMENT ARGUMENT OPERATOR format.
~         # Replace with the following:
($2$1$3)  # ( argument1 operator argument2 )
~         # No flags
```

See also [Convert from postfix notation to infix notation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5847/convert-from-postfix-notation-to-infix-notation/250890#250890), which adds parsing of operator precedence.

## Regex (<sub><sup>Perl /</sup></sub> Boost), <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```
s~([*-/] *(\d++|\((?1)\)) *(?2))(?!\))~\($1\)~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzbCsIwEETf8xWjFEkayubSqiVqP8SID1powUtRQajaX49p52GHc1imqx@XIiT9Vrl3015qvtmJz6m5XzunMZnwHPg@zeiAlPuzlF/PeaWFFyKKygjBq1mEwfNEezEEl/SLRfdob6@5v80jbbXDxMnxF6SGYVIiFixDTDTjHTFFOnqyUAAjsgpWKdJrGFUwQmYUYZJAWZbxI2ZaQo4CS0aaDFnKqaAlrWiN8g8) - Perl
**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRtj9o4EP6eXzHQqthJaAIsW0jIrlTpPpxU9UPbk@5UelFIHIganCg23TfYn146dgIbuHIRSvDMPI8fz4wnLsv@Mo73rzIe55uEwWxRFEI6FVuy@7ersrwx4lVUQVh@/QYBfOq@v7v7vhht/nl4@PvL6vpuRfbimXw1@843MMk8saztnJDbAZ1TiobbIaXktoOL5zl5PZjT5z09Z@jaYJZBWPrGi4gMNVQsWt8YGZdQVvgOWVUVFYkLLiRoTeaaCREtGX0SMvG8GANgNoPGqv5qO@NJ7kPF5KbiMPB3oCjFA5fRfcNJnxpve6PuZx0CetWl/q5ORMLybB24PmCecqSqIr5kRLu4rT9R/VkcWTdIOgkl4f2Iwiw4rhe4PtCaacaTUJPXZKag8GQAPmlRAfF9YVkHi3qyFEhHBTWbfPzrwwf/6GW5YDrEFEHQm897CK0RlnWG2f0epKUcI0VNvTN2uiDrKOPkoEYjLKvsBD3R2247pE6RMtEXgpN8@xqk42budnvIojbYVxN7PKFn1u1oaE/f2YPhGD3YG/EKK/SaUNN6O7u5/bdr13qP@51U8k/@I8qzpK5dJpkqJ6C8@lBNurG7WzUoG40dcfEIJlYEc@v22jTpKY040KSXadITGtUco2EooUAmfRc9T19Gz@NFuC6ScO1DtJEFiFYE9sg6kmGaVUKGBc8fYHvmivLcb7UTbov1mvOeD6lqLHGXyXiFhUwPZY0j7IZe1vMApWwDOBOTKb9fN84Cr@p3v4USl1BKv7iEuv8/1P0l1LpGvQng@VK6foNaIkqcoP6TQr@NSlgabXLpwcmo6f6hqujBocHSPFpCV3mwES7Nn1qFHmNtwRhBShsKbAkNwybP@BInTLmRrcqp6/eo5o8OWjKZZ5yRWlXG7Tqe@uej4pEC2lWPElV13OQxGLzMi2bGtFHqaQspNvKsI8OKlXkUM6L3tPEANgj84RFOWNT@Gh006tqJPQYpD25QHE5bz5sTJbFiwbS2clJHNMl1fWO3twYwNCwL8AMj7UWLequlCaayOyNwAQzHGbkwcl1nMIGhOzYc6A9dB7QRYDqdYgQ@mgmuYAzXhjNwhs7IuXLGzrXzzpnA9Gesqi72/VznJtSp@QU) - Boost**

Boost needs parentheses escaped in its replacement argument, because its conditional-replacement syntax uses parentheses. This isn't compatible with PCRE or Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup>, as they will interpret it as a literal `\(` and `\)`.

This exposes a bug in Boost's subroutine call processing. If `{2}` is used to match two arguments, instead of `(?2)` to match the second argument, it makes an incorrect full match. Example:

`+(+ 1 2) 3`

If the regex `([*-/]( *(\d++|\((?1)\))){2})(?!\))` is used, it matches `+(+ 1 2)` instead of the entire expression, so the closing parenthesis is added in the wrong place.

But if the regex `([*-/]( *(\d++|\(([*-/]( *\d++){2})\))){2})(?!\))` (with `(?1)` replaced with itself to one level of depth) is used instead, it correctly matches the full string.

The bug is still present in the latest version of Boost. I have [reported it](https://github.com/boostorg/regex/issues/178).

## Regex (<sub><sup>PCRE /</sup></sub> Ruby), <s>47</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```
s~([*-/]( *(\d++|\(\g<1>\))){2})(?!\))~(\1)~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVNhb5swEP3Or7ggVNsJxJC0XVNCo0ptpUzbPqyrNqnJEAFDWAkgm6xR2/SvZ2eiaeq07kORApfz@b13z75FpJa76dV1AFJECTgyAUJAjsckfNNDjPGkXtZgSQigliILpaiLKBaU8H53EobLqGjCuFrVeSHkjM6YP/vMFbGR1oYUk2EmdEHZiLJRNAyvph8uw5DZ4DHfyFOglrx1552AKMKgWcrqHkpxD5ebWNRNXpWUfMyVyssMTGUS3GMlKAU3eXMf2v3JGXkm8PS017eKmniJ6m5dZ3TuzOaRs7Uo6/b647PJ9zkntpWwfxOZ0/JnVOQJJKLIV3kjpKnpdOdiUxdVIpDLRmq2J46rddmgfNYJDl9B/CorFF6uVwshoUr/IKsWWu07GWAnVrqPhzrWlNhmf9@m/iaYzTCbRoUSvpFWeLzYpmpkqOoiRxkpg0iBFbPH1pQYDg4Al@tKUTPLV2pzfnHz7f3atLEkCIIW6BXDb0op4ior8weRQFpEaD3pW3GfaP/3nsdBQDLCrCxo5Fr4IBBN6@6j8NjfGnmZh0o01KxjKfqLKL5rJL7Ctn3TBtPxTI31ogxZ11KhhP@X/dgvudpCNIJaD4HrW0WQ4k1T9PrLxfQT89kjCqVWcYseFKLEiDnePAjMWWkyLFbrBa5g2nZtx2vbQiAm4mWlS9Duh8DzDQDN4COcVQcv7r8l8Soo/BU2OJ6tnW9BOhgs8HTuEKLQ51j7W9CwYFqF6W//GhnK/J16prddh88pdOks6fWecI6ysXc2Y4w9DraMTjoYPtOZx553b5tjo1XglCjiUZ6eOt7WPIvxRvdxuH2xETHwtZJ8kZdcj/vvpV3Pg4HR6wF@YIhuAGBGv/XfLnR1ng/BBTA4H7owdF3uncDAPTI4OAOXQ5sEGI1GWIFPiwSHcATHBvf4gA/5IT/ix/wdP4HRLw) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVNhb5swEP3Or7giq9gJxJC0XSNKo0ntpE7bPmyrNilkiIAhrA4gm6xV2@SvZ2fyYeq0DsnmOJ/fe/ds2lW7v5i1qxaIgghaJcpEiVammaAOHw1mSbJKZZdkzbqtpFAxjVkYf@baccHBUWAyKYUpqDtRd5omybubD9dJwlwIWGhVBVCi5v7iKHK0w6BbqeYeanEP1w@ZaLuqqanzsdK6qkuwte3gHpKjFNwULELo9@eXzs6B5@eDvnXaZStUN/e96VsvXqTellA2GI4uLmc/FtxxSc7@TWTf1L9SWeWQC1mtq04o29CZzsVDK5tcIJeL1OxAnDWbukP57Cg6eQXxm2pQeL1ZL4WCpviDrHtofehkjJ2Q4hBPTGwosc3RoU3zzjFbYrZIpRahVTRKpNim7lSiW1mhjIJBqoFk7Kk3JYPjY8DlttHULqu1fnh7dfv9/cZ2sSSKoh7oFcNvayWypqyrR5FDIVO03hmRbOQY/w@eZ1HklA4jZdSpjQhBIJrRPULhWbi1qrpKtOio3WZKjJZpdtcpnJK@fdsF2wtsg/WiDFk3SqOE/5f9PCz5xkI0gpLHyA@JjAq8aZp@@Xp184mF7AmFUiLn6IEUNUbMCxZRZMe1zbBYb5a4gmnXd72gbwuBmMhWjSlBux@jILQADEOIcKSNXtx/ovAqaBzSBS9wjfM9yBEGSzydO4SQ5hzbcAsGFmwi7XD71y9DWbjXOzofeHxBYUDjfDh8xv@ovAguY8bY03jL6OwIwx2NA7bb74cBjK3hEPAFExQIgBkzm88BDEyeT8AHsDif@DDxfR6cw9g/tTh4Y59DnwSYTqdYgU@PBCdwCmcWD/iYT/gJP@Vn/A0/h@lv) - PCRE2
**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJtb5swFIW/8ytOsklACBhI2zVtSRWtaIrUdlPaaZOARTQYgkRIZifrS17@enZJ0myqygdsX5/7@Ppci/nD80bAw1X3vmsJHieGCvUceQoR2FHNUyWtRJxLjrvnchY/@UJMRBPqTS5lXmaoyzopeJkoCWFE4ETb7KSjrlUsl0i8NQtss901wyg2Vx81vWFYF53LXxF7H9wr/8RFniDhRT7OZ1zs8VWVwpLTIp9pib4r0Sp4mc1GqHk4ep/2Q0yoyHI@fuACk/QfVe6xKWHtc2SSRrMjm9OFtOT8oaZNmyJwI31F3KAVWTwejgbDUSywwHK4xDCms4YK8DjiJci0wzQncoqlhz7P@NP07Kz35fZr3//cvfMPmqe3Gv/nvX975V8dFOO3ipvv1/e9696tD3yAjMccscQ3LgpVgrqEtIgzaH1qKAX473lONvJyVl36VTVWkUvExWP8LDEp9cNhmfq/A01BHmRvTCCvVkofr/VYJX/cdruZVnVuMxc24fKCEyqQTfTpJUjKfPHI391G4WV8JulYat5LrYpP5zO5hVc6Z7dTBKYTeV49LOvnlFIEtmWZbrTrFzAVOV0rDYp9ZDAg5waDjVxrQcNkkYaGFiaGsQy1MLtwOqGu6wt3pWuXNZqutdDR15uN4cBVDAM0oEVUgCLVv1o20KjirAUbUBhr2WjZNnNO4drHCoPp2gzbINBut0lB35aEIxzjRGEOc1mLHbFjdsI@sVO0/wI) - Ruby**

Ported to Ruby's subroutine syntax.

### \$\large\textit{Functions}\$

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>75</s> <s>74</s> <s>69</s> <s>67</s> 66 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to Steffan*
*-1 byte thanks to Dingus*

```
->s{0while s[/([*-\/]( *(\d++|\(\g<1>\))){2})(?!\))/]&&="(#$1)";s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzRjoIwFETf@YqR3ZhCU29bRCXduh9C@7IRXJKGGNGYxfXb2cLOw70zJ5O53r9@ptZO4jg85eO7Cw2GmlidC0eeIWfuxPmvY@78oY4uy7KnfmXscxUt@fXapuztXWWpGV7TaKXB/0Sw5@Y2GHQtxlXEl3tMTX8yo1ULDbVQ3trU9akJNtRysxHaLxVcrl1/Q1sHbxDBxBV0wjniQ5EgKpL5zjFHPnMqIIGEqJAopCR1gJZlQhBaEhYIVFUVG1HLErYosUtIkaaCtlTSjvZ0QPUH)

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/) (with [`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)), <s>107</s> <s>106</s> 105 bytes

```
import regex
f=lambda s,p=0:s==p and s or f(regex.sub('([*-/]( *(\d++|\((?1)\))){2})(?!\))',r'(\1)',s),s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1NboMwEIX3PsXrChtCxoaQBiIrB4EsiIAWyTEIU6lJ27NTg9rRaH4@vXkzPub3wabL0t/HYZoxtW/tJ@u0qe@3pobbjVoWTusRtW3gMEzo@Cbau48bD3gZxnTlCHnVRNF3xflFiUoI8ZX8CH558WOwmwJeKd@d8Pn/yT3cGU8tWec9DXq7kr2bm94WDH0H01puxPbXlLG6ah1UNihgtCll4cGmehYYp97OXDDvps5/W2sb3flzsUQKCYsi@IaUwYcna13XEOHKKYUEGFEqkUpJ6oREZowQJ5KwQSDPc6/wsTnhgAxHRooSSulAGR3plU7IfwE)

## [Python 3.8+](https://docs.python.org/3.8/) (with [`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)), <s>101</s> <s>100</s> 99 bytes

```
lambda s:[s:=regex.sub('([*-/]( *(\d++|\((?1)\))){2})(?!\))',r'(\1)',s)for i in s][-1]
import regex
```

Can't [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBboMwEETv/orpCRtK1oYkBSIrHwI5JAJSJMdBmEpN2n47tVHmsLszmn3jY/6827wYp6XXzWLOt0t7hqtqV@mpu3bfG/d14RGv45ROHDFv2iT5bTg/KtEIIX6yP8GPb/6M3qeIN8pvJ/r7hAGDhTvVqTqx4TbepxkrcHkZ93AHPLVkoWzW8sNt3NwOtmIYepjOciNwti1MoGgdNTaqYLSpZRWwofWsME6DnblgnqYOL9fZVvf@XSyJQsaSBH4hZ/DySZjBxohDTjkkwIhyiVxKUgUyuWOENJOENQTKsvQNr5WELXbYM1KUUU5b2tGePqhA@Q8) - Confirmed to work on my machine, but `regex` is not installed on TIO or ATO.

Just like in [Remove redundant parentheses](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250596/remove-redundant-parentheses/250617#250617), it's guaranteed that a fewer number of substitution iterations will be needed than the number of characters in the input, so this "do this for each character of `s`" trick works. The maximum number of substitutions approaches \$1/2\$ of the number of characters in the input string:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over {2n+2}}= {1\over 2}$$

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 100 bytes

```
[char[]]($p="$args")|%{$p=$p-replace'[*-/](?> *(\d+|\(((\()|[^)]|(?<-3>.))+\))){2}(?!\))','($&)'};$p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzRboJAFETf@Yop2cpdKL0LqJVY9UOAJsQuhYQAQRoTgW@niy@dh7l3TibTtXfd30pd14soTuOSXMu8T7KMRHeyRd7/3Gw5vY4mic7vdVfnV@0krs8ZXc5wKf32ppSIUpJT8iWziS6ffnR@l9JLpZRjONPlxXzOm0NiI535KLrF2OOkjkXb6/xakqhRNRBV0/0OcqwKEg853vtq0H7Z3obZlIMj/gH8pm30va4aDVvQRhQQtbTnxQsQWp4HcxBZMDJk9TW6cFfOERRgMUcKkVIcHBCqncXwQ8V4QiCOY9Mwei5hix32FgcccsRb3vGeP/iA@A8)

Uses [Neil's regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250879/17216) with an additional -8 byte golf. Applies the substitution the same number of times as the length of the input in characters.

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 104 bytes

```
function($s){while($p!=$s=preg_replace('~([*-/]( *(\d++|\((?1)\))){2})(?!\))~','($1)',$p=$s));return$s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5Pb4JAEMXvfIqRbMIOf7K7oFakhEtN04s2tDcxxNpFSAhuFkwPtn51uzCHnZ3fvLx5qlaP50zVCkiVPqprdxqaS0dJj7efumklJWqWkj5VWp5LLVV7PEnq3OneDdiBgkuLb8/7LSjNBBaIeAv/kGYz8707vkOJQMcnyjggJloOV92RPvl7JNVFU9KkPCFtWp3l0NOPz5e3LSZ4g6aipN33g26lSdJiIA5pahedjUbcX7/MxmCf@4HAZFI3KE/1ZZQkYFxFAuMMU@j22A@l1NocxFn6nm9ey@2u3OT5Ls/szcjXYK/JeBNNMk9AaHkemAaRBaYMGd9xdMEdOYuAA1iMRRwizplYQcgXFoMg5AwmCBDHsVGYmpxgDgtYWkywkEVszhZsyZ7YCuJ/)

Thanks to Steffan for pointing out a 1 byte golf that has the added bonus of making this anonymous rather than recursive. Knocking off an additional 2 bytes from that has the further bonus of removing the "Undefined variable" warnings from this non-recursive function.

### \$\large\textit{Full programs}\$

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>54</s> 48 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo*

```
t"'([*-/]( *(\d++|\((?1)\))){2})(?!\))' '($1)'YX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy7DsIwDEV3vuKCkOwkqpxHW5qpC5/AAKKVQGKErRvw7cEpd7DOPbb8ui/PcivLjvhqG5kZlqeHc5@JeQxmMsa849fwuFUkEO@Docu5zMdTIRcQaUPOQQFJERq1df6Fha07SfCAdpHkkbyXMCD6rho00QtWDeSc1yvN@hMtOvRVBYmSpJVOejnIgEw/)

This too applies the substitution the same number of times as the length of the input in characters.

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>51</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
1while s;([*-/]( *(\d++|\((?1)\))){2})(?!\));($1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzNDoIwEITvfYox8dDSkOkPRRoOPIh4k0QSIkRMPKivbi18h92ZL5tdhscUUrKv2zgNWFt5LkpeJArZX7X@9FJ2VvVKqbf7Ktkdcmzl0aqUtIUTWiMveIFMNtvcaoFi8/QwgCC9gTeGtoEzQRClM8QugRhjvsjsn1AhoBa0dPSsGFjzxAbxNy/Pcb6vqVz@)

## [PHP](https://php.net/) `-F`, 98 bytes

```
<?for($s=$argn;$p!=$s=preg_replace('~([*-/]( *(\d++|\((?1)\))){2})(?!\))~','($1)',$p=$s););echo$s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBPT@MwEMXP5FM8ogjbDdbkD2WpnJAbUk972CNFlUlMU6mKLSfSSqXw1btOFw68w4zn59Ebj1/12J@90R2k78AYfFWx7ZfYuWrerOfJWCfa7waVuOs6FM6b3dYbd9Ct4eyTPy8kvXAs@KZL09OG8yYXGyHEe/EheHMdjp/slvEkF@w2ccFBKKFM29tkVOfvYdEMIAfEVfPePCY@Zh8zijdDrBge0drOKPBWTwrzhQhsrTCaCdLC7Z150/uDAlk3kesdve6HOUO2IDO1kB3G3vppa50ZtpPe1b8HyKeLMSqsccLffn8wWD/9qfH1KdAKnY2uniGPSI54OZ3m4epY5@pn4wHVTfn/aZc1Eh1HnR0MyuB9TnMUUZoiJJQRggKZ41wusJg5lciAiKjMUGYZ5Q8osmVEkEVGuEBgtVqFjqCLE@6wxH1EORVU0h0t6Z5@0QNW/wA)

Comment: It's amazing how much this beats my current Python answer. Some of these snippets are probably as short as they can get in that language

Comment: Your Ruby can be 73, omitting the parens and adding a space: `->s{s.each_char{s.sub! /([*-\/] *(\d++|\(\g<1>\)) *\g<2>)(?!\))/,'(\1)'}}`

Comment: You can also save a few more by using `s.chars` instead of `s.each_char`

Comment: You can save another byte on the Ruby by [avoiding `sub!`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237027/92901): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpNboMwEAXgPad4oVVkYxn/oEpFrtOD2F60CSRIFoogURRSzk4Ns5g379MM99/n0tqFH8bXWB4vP0NKJ4gruBeBoCD@xNifJ/78pQ6eUvrSMyXfu3SKsN/bnLy9K5rP8zJZafC4dLFBtOfmNhp0LaZd4us9taY/mcmqTaPjKlib@z430UYny5LrsL3gOnT9Da2LwSDBwhR0xhhSoMqQJsm611qgWF1UkEAmRCVRSSnUJ7T8yAS4lgIbAnVd/wM "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice answer.  Something I've been wanting to know... I figure you'll know the answer.  Is there a resource which explains which regex features, or combinations thereof, are sufficient to turn a strict regex engine into a pushdown automaton, or a turing complete language?  Eg, are subexpressions alone enough?

Comment: @Jonah Thanks. And to be honest, that's not something I've looked into in detail. Regex *not* being Turing-complete is a large part of what fascinates me about it – not quite being sure what the boundaries are of what it can do, and sometimes being surprised something turns out to be possible. Though I've been thinking about designing a regex-based language that is Turing-complete, but preserves enough regex-flavor to still be appealing to me. (I feel that Retina is not that.)

Comment: @LuisMendo Very nice, thanks! Now it's even shorter than Perl!

Comment: [PHP anonymous function](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY3NSsNAFIX38xSnYWDuJGknPwgtMeQFfAExYkM6MUqZhDSBQmyXPoBbNwVx4SN165M4sd2cc-_Hved8frV1e_q5zawxXqXfQ1_Nl-fXajBl_9IY4kaOVdNRws0s5btEcpO2nX5-6nS7LUpN4kgP7lw9ElzKN573lhNlocyllGN0kJTN7HgUviAeSuHzXWojk073Q2e4SQ7XxvuE2RpdlDVI79tts9Hk5MbxsS6Lfi1R7MD3EiMDdFk3EI7AwiIrwsHv-wcuoKLpbAEnn94Tdi04ne-8EBHzPFhDbGMASyadVhfuxFWMAGBKxQHiIFDhElFwwxTmUaDwD4HVanUJ_QM)

Comment: I guess by outputting to stdout, my PHP could be two bytes shorter: [TIO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU1LasMwFNzrFBMj0JMdV_5QiFFNLtAb1KU2jlwXgmzsBAJpsuwBuu0mULrokbLtSSqn6WbmvXnzZj4--7Y_fd8tHTHe5F_bTRMuzm2ztfXmpbPErdw33UCa21nORy25zfvBPD8Npl9XtSFxpAc_VI8En4pVELwWRMtYFlLKfXKQtJy58SjmgngsxZyPuYvUpm47bvXh2ldq5kpMVbcgs-vX3cqQV1hvjrKuNqVENYLvJPYMmF4hPIEbJzkQHn7e3uEJ7Y68IefT_zavmFI0u_aczvdBjIQFARwhdTbAKRNOqw9_0lWKCGBKpRHSKFLxAkl0yxTCJFK4iECWZX-hvw).

Comment: @Steffan Thanks. I found an additional 2 bytes to be saved. As for stdout, I don't see that as being a legitimate output method for functions, regardless of how many [apparently do](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2457/17216). Anyway, I already have a PHP full program that outputs to stdout.

Answer (score 5):

## Rust Nightly, <del>332</del> <del>319</del> <del>307</del> 292 bytes

Can probably be golfed a lot more.

```rs
|b:&[char]|b.iter().chain([&' ']).scan((vec![9],1),|(a,q),&b|Some(if '0'>b{let mut o=if*q<1{*q=1;let mut u=format!("");while{let z=a.last_mut()?;*z-=1;*z<1}{a.pop();u.push(')')};u.push(b);u}else{b.into()};if b!=' '{o.insert(o.len()-1,'(');a.push(2)}o}else{*q=0;b.into()})).collect::<String>()
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0dbe926fc22712cbb2512dd45e26d65c)

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>93</s> <s>92</s> <s>90</s> <s>89</s> <s>86</s> <s>85</s> 84 bytes

```
t"t'(?<!\()[*-/]'1&XXX<t?:&)w0XH&)40hwb'\d+|[\(-/ ]'XX"@gt1)t47>Ew41>-H+XH2=?41XH]&h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcJBCoQgFADQq1gLv06I2giDQ2WbwCN8SBcTQS1mdh/czN2NHu/3oW@t1BKIMDRJyPWhdAbLEXGg8OayGIxcOnOWDdLe/dcklGYZENv5ICvJvaalODup2GHsx@AsxszPWkEz1RvNnubOvPdwAQ) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##JYmxCsIwFEV3v@LZIWkaQl6aiFZq66CQD3B40AZUBDvoFujiv8dU73A599z3Lb7SNcUi8rJv12MphkrpwA0jojb2eyZmJM@Ew2m@8/EhP8NYKg2BExXHZzQium13np3plJfk60PvDPnAphRCoNMlcWmg5isuJWQAmxFysl36Lyqolk9bQIC8tbYIFlGbHdS4WQyoGjX8NEDTNPwL).

The code uses a non-recursive approach, based on the facts that

- each operator must have a `(` immediately before, and
- the corresponding `)` must be placed immediately after the first number for which the count of numbers minus operators to the right of the  `(` equals `2`.

The procedure is as follows:

Repeat these steps as many times as the input length (it would suffice to repeat as many times as the number of operators in the input string):

1. Find the first operator (`+-/*`) that is not predeced by `(`, if any.
2. Insert `(` right before that.
3. Take the substring after that position until the end and split it into groups, where each group is either a number (one or more digits), an operator, an opening or closing parenthesis, or whitespace (one or more spaces).
4. Start a counter at `0`. For each group from the previous step, increment the counter if the group is a number, and decrement it if the group is an operator.
5. When the counter reaches `2`, insert `)` right after that group.

Comment: Using a regexp substitution is [30 bytes shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250875/17216) :-)

Comment: @Deadcode Well done! :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), 102 bytes

```
f(s++t)|all(<'!')t=g s++t
g(' ':s)=' ':g s
g s|all(>'/')s=s
g(c:s++t)|elem c"+-*/"='(':c:g s++g t++")"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczBToQwEAbgO0/x05i0pZIpsKwLEe4ejAePxhhCWNwIK6HdGBPfHduuNmk7@eaf6S/r@p0u3Udvtu0ojFJW/nTTJO55zKVtRniKRsHBayMb/zmL3A2xlhOXpnEg@vo6PUzDjJ6pNCHWcMHrvg5bRlilmGSbHYxFXePZrqfziLTFwxOEjIIbNFgu1vUgzPvnF4xE2/4T82nmQSxu2OImjnF0mSiau9PZzc7d8viGsOqFqQw5uwVTCq5C4Wu449y/f5Ig8V0qoAEPRIVGoTVlB@S6DIQ014TgQFVV15w7YTF2KLEPllFOBe2opD3d0QEVe91@AQ)

Answer (score 5):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/), <del>292</del> <del>274</del> <del>125</del> <del>91</del> 129 bytes

- -18 bytes thanks to Steffan
- -999999 bytes thanks to Seffan
- -19 bytes thanks to JoKing
- -15 bytes by myself :). I realized I didn't really need to return the value "Z" since it's only possible value could be a space.
- +28 bytes to fix spacing bug :(

Just like my other answer inputs require a trailing space. I'm very new to prolog so this is probably nowhere near optimal.

```
N+Z:-N=32,$N,\X,X+Z;N/Z.
$N:-put(N).
\N:-get0(N).
32/32.
X/Z:-X<48,$40,$X,\D,D+W,W+Z,$41;X^Z.
X^Z:-X>48,$X,\W,W^Z;X=Z.
:- \X,X+_.
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##HY2xDsIwDET3fEWGDKA4SZt0QAll6uy1VhSVCVWVkFpBEZ8fTJeTfffs217rc53N@7vUijpHg33woBAKAemc0GUrFEazffYTnq0oPM@PvTmW4F3wVpDjQ7p2F1BdA4qgDDDoEUad2WkTTfyEhaHbH2KAwykn6jmIRh5ld1urdK13XgYpfw)

Comment: `get_code` can be `get0`, and you can remoev the space after `:-`.

Comment: some simple golfs for [139](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoMwEEXXzSlmkYXBSapJbMFDZGtMUwoFEaGiWEuPn06ks3v/v/nrtryWUb6/U0oxtHIc9qpwAl0ZFOOuletnJ1bMaGm0Yl6SNA/zc9gKjzdr0Gq0DdrrXSC3FXKPsUPeYQzE9f8DKD6me4G9DHmuPGKjSSQpk88FhfGhUoLTOV8NGgxYaOACPw). can be way shorter, will work on this later.

Comment: removed the `halt` because I thought you didn't need it, but you can add it back if you think you need it for it to be valid

Comment: [125](https://tio.run/##LYzNCsIwEAbP5in2kIOlu7H5UaSIj5BrtyHgSYogtGjFx4@b4t5mdviW1/ycJ3p/H6Xk1NN0X7t9bDC2ySgde1o@q7BR3pF3RjFJxNdgkS/hjDp0qBnzgHrAnITtvwHR29jY4EipDrSb9k5CiSpxfYjMN1MK7A71LDjwEOAIJ/gB)

Comment: I asked in chat and they said I needed the halt

Comment: I don't feel like it really counts as my answer anymore if you remove 1/3rd of it

Comment: I'm gonna instead try to apply some tips from your answer but only the ones I understand

Comment: Feel free to submit your version though if you like

Comment: feel free to post mine, it's based on your method so if I wrote it it would be different.

Comment: you forgot to update your TIO link. One more quick golf: `X-Z:- $X,get0(Y),Y-Z.` -> `X-Z:-get0(Y),$X,Y-Z.`

Comment: The `X>41,` is actually not needed - the input accidentally had a tab in it.

Comment: You can combine the `(\)/1` and `(+)/2` predicates for [106 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYzLCsIwEEX3@YpZZNHAzNg8FEnVT5ht0xBwJUUQWrTi58fo3R0u56zP5bHM9Prcay050nzb@k4MdnL2DrVgyYNQNqy0RFrfWztZeUfesUrUjHQJFtMpHFGHHnXCMqIem9fYDo3/ycngRJlVJChXrhV2v1lw4CHAHg7wBQ)

Comment: Make that [101](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsIwEEX3OcUsZtHATNomUSTVK2TbNARcSREKLVrx@Ono3z0@722vdVlnfn@ftZYceH7sXRM1NfHmLGGkkofIWRuFMfD22eU0yll21qjEYqSrvxD6jjBRGQlHUYT7QfhfmzRNnI0KDOVuaoX2tx4sOPBwgjMc "Prolog (SWI) – Try It Online") with removing `X>41,`.

Comment: I hate to rain on your parade, but the question requires that trailing spaces be preserved, which your 91-byte version does not do.

Comment: Yea I just figured it out. Jo King's solution has the same problem though

Comment: [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsMgEEX3nsKFi4aMmmgWRZMeYbYOIumqhEIgoU3J8e20mw@P9/j7a1u3Rb/PZ63Y5qBx8g4UQskRbTZCYdD757hgY0RhvzyOjgE4NsI7650RZFnQOFxBDR0ogpIgtZmpjzRzx8PB7RcQ/B9SA2nOkSa2QctyN7VK2zvrpJfyCw "Prolog (SWI) – Try It Online")

Comment: Wait this still doesn't preserve trailing spaces. If this was valid, you could also remove `32/32.` because it is never called with spaces.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 50 bytes

```
W#aI@aQsOPOaEIaLT0OxPBt&'(.POaEL{Oa~XIa:$'WDQxO')}
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJXI2FJQGFRc09QT2FFSWFMVDBPeFBCdCYnKC5QT2FFTHtPYX5YSWE6JCdXRFF4TycpfSIsIlwiXCIiLCIiLCJcIiArLyAtMjAvIDMwIDMwICA5OTkyIDBcIiJd) (Note: the footer is because DSO doesn't flush the output buffer until a newline is output.)

#### Explanation

Loop through the input string.

- If the first character is a space, pop and output it.
- If the first character is an operator:

  - Output an open paren.
  - Pop and output the operator.
  - Push 1 (representing a close-paren) and 0 (representing the space between an operator's first and second operands) to a stack.
- Else (this is a number):

  - Output the first run of digits in the string.
  - Remove the first run of digits from the string.
  - Pop the stack; while the result is 1, output a close-paren and repeat.

#### Ungolfed

```
$expr: a
$stack: ""
W # $expr {
 I @ $expr Q " " {
  O PO $expr
 } EI $expr LT "0" {
  O '(
  O PO $expr
  $stack PB 1
  $stack PB 0
 } EL {
  O $expr ~ `^\d+`
  $expr : $'
  W DQ $stack {
   O ')
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 129 bytes

```ruby
f=->(s){def k a;i,j=a.shift;j=~/\d/?(i+j): i+"("+j+k(a)+k(a)+")"end;h,t=s.scan(/(.*[^ ])( *)$/)[0];k(h.scan(/( *)([0-9]+|.)/))+t}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzdasJAEEbvfYqPxYuZrNlZEwpNQ@qDpBFWY8iPiDTxQqq@erq2CMa5@C7OOcz3aXMexyoLP6nnn3JXoYNLm0WbOdPXTTWkbXaTr1JW1OiWP9BoRUq3uiPH/6NY7Q5lWi@GrDf91h1IyAT5GgUTAp4L57ZIO6of0kPKbZgU@mJYmPVwHY@ozNbt9/73EpHi2RPQ8AjxBMKfL@/7qgIE915iWGBiRGKL2FpZviOyb1OHMLKCvwBIkkTx@As)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>67</s> <s>66</s> 58 bytes

```
+`[*-/](?> *\d+| *\(((\()|[^)]|(?<-2>.))+\)){2}(?!\))
($&)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYu9CgIxEIT7PMUIIrsJcfcSBANyeZDLiYIWNhZiZ3z2c88p5ueDed3fj@d1WcJl8lFmqiN8u4VuTkSNuE9nnjvVU0zjnjk05k/6Ut1YcbTdsX0HJBcCLJAdTEZWX6eHX7lkKOBEsiKrynBE0oMTxKSCPwRKKT8) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Much like @Deadcode's answer, the expression tries to find unparenthesised expressions to parenthesise. Explanation:

```
+`
```

Repeat until no more substitutions can be made.

```
[*-/]
```

Match an operator. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @Deadcode.

```
(?> *\d+
```

Atomically match an integer parameter, ...

```
| *\(((\()|[^)]|(?<-2>.))+\))
```

... or a balanced parenthesised parameter, ... (Edit: Saved a further 8 bytes thanks to @Deadcode)

```
{2}
```

... twice.

```
(?!\))
```

Ensure that the operator wasn't previously parenthesised. (This test shamelessly stolen from @Deadcode to save 1 byte.)

```
($&)
```

Parenthesise the operator and its parameters.

Alternative approach, <s>60</s> 58 bytes:

```
(?<=(()\d+|[^*-/]|(\2|())(?<-2>.))*)\d+
$&$#4$*)
[*-/]
($&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYq9CgIxEIT7fYoB47GbEDeXKBjwp/Qh7hQPtLCxEMu8e0ycYob5Zj7P7@u91DVf7pXPhyOzzA9Xppv1ei08x8IibfDxtBGxfSQzmNXWWKGpn4jNUKsbEck5tEAiNDXSvVcL27kmBIBUU0AKQcc9YtiRwseg@EMg5/wD) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
(?<=(()\d+|[^*-/]|(\2|())(?<-2>.))*)\d+
$&$#4$*)
```

Consider the minimum number of integers that would complete the prefix expression at any given point; this value increases at an operator and (obviously) decreases at an integer. Working back from a given integer, up to the point that the value decreases below the current value, count the number of times it is equal. This is the number of parentheses that should be appended.

```
[*-/]
($&
```

Prefix a `(` to each operator.

Comment: This is not fully parenthesizing the last test case, `/ -20/ 30 30  999`.

Comment: @Deadcode Ugh I can't believe it took me over half an hour to spot that missing `?`...

Comment: Oopsie! But any reason you didn't use the character class `[*-/]` to save 1 byte?

Comment: @Deadcode Partly because I had already forgotten by then and partly because I don't like mixing golfs with bugfixes.

Comment: You can drop the `(?(2)^)` and change the `[^()]` to `[^)]` for -8 bytes, because the expression is already atomicized and the parentheses are guaranteed to be balanced since your own regex is what created them.

Comment: @Deadcode This means that it now outgolfs the alternative approach I had had (but have only just got around to writing up).

Comment: Well, I'd like to see that alternative approach anyway, please :-)

Comment: @Deadcode ... I already edited it into my answer?

Comment: Oh yeah :-) interesting that it's only +2 bytes – worth trying to golf further. Oh, and not that either actually need ``%(G`‍`` in their header, but the harness for your alternative approach is missing it.

Comment: @Deadcode It's often only when the test suite breaks that I remember to add it in. Also, I think I found a 2 byte saving, so they're both the same length now.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 47 bytes

```
O({a:POysNa?a.VfaLT0?pJa.(fMJt)a}Y(aw,+XD,XX))y
```

This is a different enough approach that I thought it warranted its own answer. [Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJPKHthOlBPeXNOYT9hLlZmYUxUMD9wSmEuKGZNSnQpYX1ZKGF3LCtYRCxYWCkpeSIsIiIsIiIsIlwiICsvIC0yMC8gMzAgMzAgIDk5OSAwICBcIiJd)

#### Explanation

First, we tokenize the input:

```
(aw,+XD,XX)
 a           Command-line argument
(         )  Find all matches of this regex:
  w            Run of whitespace
   ,           or
    +XD        Run of digits
       ,       or
        XX     Any single character
```

Now we're going to run a recursive descent parser on this list of tokens, popping each token as it's parsed. Unfortunately, functions in Pip are call-by-value rather than call-by-reference, so we store the list in the global variable `y` and modify that at each step. This also means our function doesn't actually take any arguments. Calling a function with no arguments can be a bit tricky in Pip, so sometimes we'll call it with a dummy argument that gets ignored.

```
{a:POysNa?a.VfaLT0?pJa.(fMJt)a}
{                             }  Recursive function, parses y and returns a parenthesized string
   POy                           Pop the first token from y
 a:                              Store it in the local variable a
      sNa?                       If it contains a space (whitespace token):
          a.                      Concatenate it to
            Vf                    a recursive call to the current function
              aLT0?              Else, if it is lexicographially earlier than "0" (operator):
                     a.(    )     Concatenate it to
                        f          the current function
                         MJ        called on each character in
                           t       "10" (i.e., called twice)
                                   and the results joined into a single string
                   pJ             Join the string "()" on the above result
                             a   Else (number token), just return the token
```

This function parses exactly one expression. In particular, if the input had trailing spaces, the final whitespace token is not parsed and remains in `y`. Therefore, the overall program is:

```
O({...}Y(...))y
        (...)    Tokenize the input
       Y         Yank the list of tokens into y
 (           )   Call, with that argument
  {...}          the parser function
O                Output the resulting parenthesized expression without a newline
              y  Autoprint the remainder of y, if any, with a trailing newline
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 186 bytes

```
lambda s,a=[]:(t:=s.rstrip(),[a:=c<'!'and a[:-1]+[c+a[-1]]or a+[c.isdigit()and c or"("+c+a.pop()+a.pop()+")"]for c in re.findall("\d+|.",t)[::-1]],a)[2][-1]+' '*(len(s)-len(t))
import re
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PU9LboNADF2HU7hssBl-AVVKULlFd4TFAKEdicBomC4q9SbdRKraI3TRm-Q29SS0s7Cfn5-fPe9f-tU-z9P5Y6gOny92iHeXn1Ge2l7CEsmqbkq0ZbUkZrFGaaSolmXVPQR3gZx6kHUZbxtRd0LWDJrZgOQqUUuvnpRFcqIOZuOjL1iU6Jk9_rNPfjPwTAdqAnNMBjX1chzRP_TiLfEjS3XpFjSRpDpv3AoRQBDieJxwodglS-Spk56NZYf1B4_OVDnTWbMko9IDGbWVup6bLHrk2_yD9ckDbdRkcUBJVdVG5qgNw1t25Apbopv3-fIttpBv0EXyhADOUHCNV0hQsCk_7rvoeg7grUZH8MUhhG4uLSAD2GAIGF6H0TFEAF6aFhkUWZZud5Bn9xtMcWUIV459UojzLIVrA2C_37MOkDlcSefF9N_5vw)

Handling trailing whitespace added a lot of bytes, even though leading whitespace didn't.

If we didn't have to handle trailing whitespace:

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 149 bytes

```
lambda s,a=[]:[a:=c<'!'and a[:-1]+[c+a[-1]]or a+[c.isdigit()and c or"("+c+a.pop()+a.pop()+")"]for c in re.findall("\d+|.",s)[::-1]][-1][-1]
import re
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PU5BboNADDyHV7h7ia0lQIIqJaj8ojfCYYHQrkRgtdBDpT6jPfUSqWr_lN_UJrQr2R6Px975_HGv0_PQX77a_Pj9MrWb_fWjM-eqMTCGJi_KrDBZXj-s79amb8AU2WZb6qLWpmBQDh4Md5EdG_tkJyQR1TB4hUqzKHKDQ_qvilTZ8k4Ntgd_ilrbN6brUB0b_RapcKQikw9KOS4R2LMb_MTaxdyjrFtZH9ypx4SyAExY5XY2Fo2uYxfqOCkKwHnbT9iioTyvQn9ynuGtCrnAiuh2-3J911vYrVAyBVoDV0i5xxkSpHyUH88ly0wA3noUgiiI4zSBNEni7R52yf0KY1wYwoUTFWx2SQzzAOBwOLAOkDlcSKKZ_jP3Cw)

If there was no whitespace or multi-digit numbers:

### [Python](https://www.python.org), 90 bytes

```
lambda s,a=[]:[a:=a+[c.isdigit()and c or"("+c+a.pop()+a.pop()+")"]for c in s[::-1]][-1][0]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3o3ISc5NSEhWKdRJto2OtohOtbBO1o5P1MotTMtMzSzQ0E_NSFJIV8ouUNJS0k7UT9QryCzQ04bSSplJsWn4RUEVmnkJxtJWVrmFsbDSQiDaIhdiwuaAoM69EI01DSV_XSN_Y2FJJUxMis2ABhAYA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 46 bytes

```
⊞υω⭆θ⎇№+-*/ι∧⊞Ｏ⊞Ｏυ⁺⊟υ)ω⁺(ι⎇›№⭆χλι№⭆χλ§θ⊕κ⁺ι⊟υι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7LDoIwEEX3fEXT1YyWgLoirowLw8JIoj/QQCNELDi0Pr6@FsQQF04mmczrnpuXkvJG1s5ltivBCvbAdZBRpQ0cjS/nvWzhJthJkZb0gm1j/YrPw1nEBatQsI0uoH8@tIqkaei38YpZbTvImhasv@bIEXvKOOcwyOBE2JGSRtFImkwsYsFq/DD/7TYm1YV69oZTnZO6Km1UARdE/AIrXwcvg5SPtXMRC5dxxFZxnyxJksCF9/oN) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υω
```

Start with `0` on top of the stack.

```
⭆θ
```

Loop through the input characters.

```
⎇№+-*/ι
```

If this is an operator, then...

```
∧⊞Ｏ⊞Ｏυ⁺⊟υ)ω
```

... increment the top of the stack, push `0` to the top of the stack, and...

```
⁺(ι
```

... output the operator prefixed with a `(`.

```
⎇›№⭆χλι№⭆χλ§θ⊕κ
```

Otherwise, if this is a digit but the next isn't, then...

```
⁺ι⊟υ
```

... output the digit followed by a number of `)`s given by the top of the stack.

```
ι
```

Otherwise, just output the character.

Answer (score 3):

## [nearley](https://nearley.js.org), 78 bytes

```
m->_ p _{%a=>a.flat(1/0)%}
p->[\d]:+|[-+/*] _ p _ p{%a=>['(',a,')']%}
_->" ":*
```

Post-processing functions for production rules, denoted by `{%...%}`, are evaluated in JavaScript. Each function is called with an array of post-processed results for each terminal or non-terminal from which the rule is produced.

This [EBNF grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) is defined by three non-terminal production rules `m`, `p`, and `_`.

- `_` is zero or more spaces
- `p` is one or more digits OR one of `-`, `+`, `/`, `*` followed by `_`, `p`, `_`, then `p`.
- `m` is `_`, `p`, then `_`.

The post-processing function of `p` wraps the result in parentheses when it is produced by `[-+/*] _ p _ p`, and the post-processing function of `m` flattens the nested array of characters produced from parsing the complete input.

You can test it in the [Nearley Parser Playground](https://omrelli.ug/nearley-playground/), but you'll need to add the the code above and the test cases yourself since there's no permalink feature.

Alternatively, if you're comfortable with the Developer Tools in your browser, you can evaluate the following snippet on the console while loaded on that page to save yourself from having to insert the test cases manually.

```
localStorage.playgroundState=String.raw`{"active":0,"compiled_grammar":"module.exports={ParserRules:[{name:'m',symbols:['_','p','_'],postprocess:a=>a.flat(1/0)},{name:'p$ebnf$1',symbols:[/[\\d]/]},{name:'p$ebnf$1',symbols:[/[\\d]/,'p$ebnf$1'],postprocess:a=>[a[0],...a[1]]},{name:'p',symbols:['p$ebnf$1']},{name:'p',symbols:[/[-+/*]/,'_','p','_','p'],postprocess:a=>['(',a,')']},{name:'_$ebnf$1',symbols:[]},{name:'_$ebnf$1',symbols:[{literal:' '},'_$ebnf$1'],postprocess:a=>[a[0],...a[1]]},{name:'_',symbols:['_$ebnf$1']}],ParserStart:'m'}","tabs":[{"name":"Add parentheses to Polish notation","editor_value":"m->_ p _{%a=>a.flat(1/0)%}\np->[\\d]:+|[-+/*] _ p _ p{%a=>['(',a,')']%}\n_->\" \":*","errors":[],"tests":["+1 2","++ 1 2 3","    +1    +2 3","* *1 2 /3 0  ","//30 300/18 205","/ -20/ 30 30  999","/////1 2 3 4 5 6","/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 9"]}]}`;location.reload()
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>178</s> <s>177</s> 175 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)*

```
S/L:-atom_codes(S,L).
[C|T]*P*R:-C=32,T*Q*R,P=[C|Q];C>47,[C|T]+P+R;T*E*Q,Q*F*R,append([[40,C],E,F,[41]],P).
[N|T]+[N|P]+R:-N>47,T+P+R.
X+_+X.
S^T:-S/L,L*P*R,append(P,R,M),T/M.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc7BCoJAEAbgu08xdNLd2TXNChS7SJ0sVt2DIKtISgiVUkGX3t12g@Ywh@Gfb2Z6jNfxwp7vYZ4LNw1Z@xpvzXns@qddYOpwq0o@UhFB8pAl8cpHSTKSo4j1PFNRsgu2@ItQQfNIkj3JMCMHHWmnqb93dlUFS0wU7vGAVeAphcKoJ7Oiu1BUyyfDSENwq6QNLblV1DJk@iVMzfG/JjDHo4PSPfI5ZAsAVxe4nueB78MKAljDBmBRlwjvx/Dq7dLh8xc)

#### Explanation

The other Prolog answer cleverly reads characters from stdin one at a time. I wanted to try a more "traditional" solution, a predicate which takes a string and generates another string.

```
S/L:-atom_codes(S,L).
```

Define the `/` operator as a shortcut for converting an atom or string to a list of codepoints and vice versa.

```
[C|T]*P*R:-
```

The `*` operator is the main workhorse here. It takes a list of codepoints (the first of which is `C` and the remainder of which are `T`) and parses one Polish-notation expression from the beginning of it, returning the correctly parenthesized parsed expression in `P` and the rest of the list of codepoints in `R`. It has three branches:

```
C=32,T*Q*R,P=[C|Q]
```

If `C` is a space, parse everything after the space and prepend a space to the result.

```
C>47,[C|T]+P+R
```

If `C` is a digit, parse a run of digits using the `+` operator (defined below).

```
T*E*Q,Q*F*R,append([[40,C],E,F,[41]],P).
```

Otherwise, `C` is an operator. Parse a subexpression `E`, then parse another subexpression `F`. Finally, concatenate an open paren, the operator `C`, both subexpressions, and a close paren together to form the result `P`.

To parse a run of digits:

```
[N|T]+[N|P]+R:-N>47,T+P+R.
```

If the list of codepoints starts with a digit `N`, parse a run of digits from the portion following `N`, and prepend `N` to the result.

```
X+_+X.
```

Otherwise, the remainder is the same as the input. The result is a "don't care" (`_`), which apparently works because (based on its use in the calling predicate) it has to be a list, and the empty list is the first possibility Prolog tries.

The `^` operator is the main predicate:

```
S^T:-S/L,L*P*R,append(P,R,M),T/M.
```

It takes a string `S`, converts it to a list of codepoints `L`, parses `L` into a parenthesized expression `P` and remainder `R`, concatenates `P` and `R` into `M` (so as to keep any trailing spaces), and converts `M` back into the string result `T`.

---

If I can take and return lists of codepoints instead of strings, this solution is **145 bytes**:

```
[C|T]*P*R:-C=32,T*Q*R,P=[C|Q];C>47,[C|T]+P+R;T*E*Q,Q*F*R,append([[40,C],E,F,[41]],P).
[N|T]+[N|P]+R:-N>47,T+P+R.
X+_+X.
X^Y:-X*P*R,append(P,R,Y).
```

Comment: `X+[]+X.` can just be `X+_+X.` because if that point is reached, we know that the list is empty.

Comment: Why not have I/O as list of charcodes, like [this](https://tio.run/##NY1NC4JAGITv/oqXTrr7qvlRgWIX0ZPIKntYWNYU@iCoFA26RH/d1qA5zGGYeWYY@1t/safXdZ5l@uaKMFJHdpoEPnJSkRpZovNKxek@3OGvQhmtY04yUmFFcl3phuH0OJpShmtMFWaYoww9pZBZjiHLZaKdKarJ5YLhC8IxBD1Q4RhFwyO7WI7/JIY1csuZI7sFcLXA9TwPfB8CCGEDW4C2EQjnfrx3T3P1mVYIUig9@QI)?

Comment: @Steffan [I can't remember if that's allowed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61920045#61920045), but if so, that's the alternate solution at the bottom of the post already. ;)

Comment: You can use `atom_codes` instead of `string_codes` and itw ill still work with strings.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 226 bytes

```py
lambda s:f(s)[0]
import re
f=lambda s:((' '*O[0].count(' '))+'('+O[0].lstrip()+(J:=f(s[len(O[0]):]))[0]+(T:=f(J[1]))[0]+')',T[1])if(O:=re.findall('^(?:\s+)*[\*\-\+/]',s))else((O:=re.findall('^(?:\s+)*\d+',s))[0],s[len(O[0]):])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5Ba4QwFITv/op3y0vibqJSWAXpbQ972cvejAVblQayGhL3sL/eJlJaLDSHwMw3zBv7XD7nqThZt55rtZru/t534KsRPW1km@i7nd0CbkjG@gciEiDsGvjxY35MS5SUcoKEb6bxi9MWKcdLVYemxgwTRkKrlsZajrcILk32rQkl6S0qPeK1qt1wHPXUd8YgecPXSnlOWaOYOiguWpJ6SgfjB/w3q3q@pUJ3uj@/WqfD4nPYmkEeZie/BodgQbEzIbyQjP9fxIDFvChAAuyIEIWEQkqRnSCXL3sGh1wK2AIAZVkGun4B)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 174 bytes

```
#define p putchar(
f(char *x){int s[100]={0},*S=s,b,c;for(;*x;){if(b=*x==32)p*x++);for(c=0;isdigit(*x);b=c=1)p*x++);for(*S+=c;*S==2;)p')'),*S=0,*--S+=1;b||++S+p'(')+p*x++);}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZLBboMwDIa1IzyF1R2wExABNKlVlqfosUJTS0uXw1pUqITU8iS79NLr3md7mjkZVOMQ7P-zfyyHz3v1tq-q2-1-7upk_v31vN3V9rCDBppzV72vTxjW6N4gerrYQwftKlOqNBc1xGJp2ngTV7o-nlCLXnNFjRsjemOKnBrRS0keVkZp227t3nbIRnpjKpP9LxBLaSrNhibX1EQUkXNXsUgSJpneXK9SLmUTYURy7BuGv6l_ntYfa3tAuoSBH9UeV6WfEgywFsxkBvksdhG6kDj2sgTOoJgQ-pygmAqAH25w56PMZfgnolNpKhYgnFtagBoNBaDwhuhEIgAPHEvTQkGhVJrNIVcvY0OKo0w4god7CkmuUvAYYLFYTC2ADHAk7hvMaBYGg-Y-Xi2guzXLFwD2Ncv5lCZ3qwpq5EXZkvTjrjNFmgGnrWcyK50whOOmp__kFw)

Note: as it is, it works up to `100` nested brackets.

Comment: You don't need the space in `char *x`

Comment: couldn't you set the size to 999, same amount of bytes with more storage, or is the 100 significant?

Comment: @Samathingamajig yes, you can. 100 was just the first number I typed in

Comment: [166 bytes](https://tio.run/##TZHPboMwDMbP8BRed8BOQATQpFVZnoJjxaGw0kXqH1Q6CYny6mNOBtVySOzvZ3@JnCY5Ns08v34eWns5QCe773vztb9h2KI7xUBje72hvdyh32VKVWacYlGaPq7jRotB14@HlCV0EUbUiUFKotG2WBsxGFPki6adSWOUtv2nPdo7srGuTWOy/wWilIZNS2NyLaVIkpI4eekiikhP03ze2wvSGAbuaWCvu8o/CQywFmxkBvkmdhG6kDj2sgTOoFgR@pygWAuAFze4/VnmMvwT0am0FgsQzi0tQC2GAlB4Q3QiEYAHjqVpoaBQKs3eIVdvS0OKi0y4gKd7CkmuUvAYYLvdri2ADHAh7g5mtAmDSXMfzw78F1meMNiPLOddmtyNKmiRB2Ur0rD@baZIM@C090xmlROmcJp/mva0P/Zzcjr/Ag "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>32</s> 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÎĆü2vyÇн₆%Ígi'(?>0}y¬?dRJi')×?
```

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cN@RtsN7jMoqD7df2PuoqU31cG96prqGvZ1BbeWhNfYpQV6Z6pqHp9v//x@tpK@ko6QAxLpAbATEBkAMEzOG8tHZIGwJx7EA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVnlopb2SwqO2SQpK9pXBof8NIo60Hd5jVFZ5uP3C3kdNbaqHe9Mz1TXs7QxqKw@tsU8J8spU1zw83f5/be2hbfb/tQ0VjLi0tRWAlIIxlwIQAEVAJIirpaAFEtc3VjDg0tc3NlAwNjDQN7RQMDIw5dJX0DUy0FcACyooWFpaAlUAAdgcBRMFUwUzLn1DfSN9Y30TfVN9M31zfQsFSwA).

Port of [*@Neil*'s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250895/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

**Explanation:**

```python
Î              # Push 0 and the input character-list
 Ć             # Enclose it; append its own head
  ü2           # Pop and push its overlapping pairs
 v             # Loop over each pair of characters `y`:
  y            #  Push the current pair `y`
   Ç           #  Convert both to its codepoint integer
    н          #  Pop and leave just the first integer
     ₆%        #  Modulo-36
       Í       #  +2
        g      #  Then pop and push the length
         i     #  If this is 1 (which means it's an operator character):
          '(? '#   Print "("
          >    #   Increase the current value by 1
          0    #   Push a new 0
         }     #  Close the if-statement
  y            #  Push pair `y` again
   ¬           #  Push its first character (without popping the pair)
    ?          #  Pop and output this first character
     d         #  Check for both characters whether they're digits
      R        #  Reverse the pair
       J       #  Join them together to a string
        i      #  If this is "01":
         ')×  '#   Pop the top value, and push a string with that many ")"
            ?  #   Pop and print it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>136</s> <s>132</s> 125 bytes

```c
#define p putchar(
x;*s;r(n){for(;*s&&n<2;x||p*s<40?n--,*s++:p'(')+!!r(!p*s++))))for(x=!++n;*s>47;)x=p*s++);}f(*a){s=a;r(0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDvboIwEP8sT3GwTK8goYDLppXtBfYGygeC4EhYJYAJifLqY9eimCzZfWj7@3dtL3XTMpHHYXg6ZHkhM6igOrfpV1Kj0Qm7ETVKdslPNRKYz@U2EN31WtnNdsU/pOsu7cZxNtUCF8wxzRrNShGMSmW6yHQcScn31atgXTSKos/RTtiliRJqzwkP30khkV2MWSFbKE67eOdzHkMERM0@LceHwFrqI6ozIzAKDhCEcBJREwzCyQJUlFHrw6ggjiwqmk12G2zV0QuB35vagLZuioplDEArWvS8kEPIuee/QcBf7hEPbzzDm/K4wQM34B5oHWC9Xk8hQFLwJql7SGSWMesFJWmegHo8ERdQbP2AVicKaGrwp6qafDlaz2Wzl1lXZWmbHTagYZ0157IF2NAn1KSLeNyABhczQS/JUdNMwL@N93IvLWXujX74SfMyOTbDLw)