# Translate an arithmetic expression to Brainfuck

Tags: code-golf, brainfuck, compiler

Write a program that translates an arithmetic expression to a Brainfuck program which evaluates the expression and prints the result in decimal numbers. For example, this arithmetic expression,

```
2 * (3 + 4)
```

can be translated to Brainfuck as,

```
++ 2
>+++ 3
>++++ 4
[-<+>]< add
<[>[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]<<-]>[-]>>[-<<<+>>>]<<< mul
[->+<]>[>>>>++++++++++<<<<[->+>>+>-[<-]<[<<[->>>+<<<]>>>>+<<-<]<<]
++++++++[->++++++<]>[-<+>]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<[-]<<<]<[.<] print decimal
```

The Brainfuck program doesn't take input. However, each integer constant or operator in the original expression must have a distinct translated form contained in the resulting Brainfuck program.

This is the definition of an arithmetic expression.

```
primary-expression
  integer-constant
  (arithmetic-expression)

multiplicative-expression
  primary-expression
  multiplicative-expression multiplicative-operator primary-expression

additive-expression
  multiplicative-expression
  additive-expression additive-operator multiplicative-expression

arithmetic-expression
  additive-expression

additive-operator
  + | -

multiplicative-operator
  * | /

integer-constant
  a decimal constant in the range [0-255],
  which cannot start with '0' unless the number is 0
```

In other words, a `multiplicative-expression` is evaluated before an`additive-expression`. An `arithmetic-expression` enclosed in parentheses is evaluated prior to the outer expressions. Otherwise, a chain of expressions is evaluated from left to right.

All whitespaces are ignored.

The Brainfuck machine to run the output will have 8-bit cells, each holding an unsigned integer. It is guaranteed that `255 + 1 == 0` and `0 - 1 == 255`, so you can use this fact to implement your Brainfuck operations. At the same time, you may safely assume that the initial input of an arithmetic expression does not overflow or underflow during its evaluation.

This is a `code-golf` challenge.

---

The print function in the example BF code won't print anything if it reads 0. However, your program's BF output should print 0 if the result of the expression is 0. This BF function for example will print 0 for 0, but it's longer.

```
>>++++++++++<<[->+>-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<<]>>[-]>>>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]
>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]>>[>++++++[-<++++++++>]<.<<+>+>[-]]<[<[->-<]
++++++[->++++++++<]>.[-]]<<++++++[-<++++++++>]<.[-]<<[-<+>]<
```

You are free to find or make a shorter version for any BF operation. [Here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms) is a list of common operations implemented in BF. [This](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/) is a webpage where you can test BF code and also look at the memory dump.

Comment: @Arnauld The BF program doesn't have an input. The challenge is to translate a human-readable arithmetic expression to brainfuck terms. I've edited for clarity.

Comment: I see what you mean now, thank you for clarifying. This might be a borderline [non-observable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11197/58563), although it applies to the output rather than the solution itself. (I personally think that's OK, but let's see what others have to say about that.)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This looks like a fun challenge, but I think the lack of a specified way of converting it will make it difficult to determine what counts as enough computation.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I've made an edit to clarify. The BF program should be a "literal" translation of the expression.

Comment: @xiver77 That's still difficult to objectively verify, unfortunately. There's going to be a subjective line between optimizing the output and no longer literally translating the input.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms As I wrote "each integer constant or operator must have a distinct translated form contained in the resulting Brainfuck program", the borderline is objectively clear, I think.

Comment: May we assume that the final result is an unsigned byte? (e.g. `2*(3-4)` would print `254`) Also, your example code would print nothing at all for `0`. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: I'm almost done with this challenge, but I don't know much brainfuck. What are the instruction sequences for subtracting and dividing on a stack-like structure like the one in the example output? Edit: I already have add and mul since those were given in the example output.

Comment: I figured out subtraction. Now I only need to know division.

Comment: @Arnauld Made edits. You can ignore overflow or underflow. The print function's behavior was unintended. I added a different one which can print 0.

Comment: @JosephWalker https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms may help. See the added lines from the edit I just made.

Comment: Is the result of a division guaranteed to be an integer?  If not, how should the result be rounded?

Comment: @Nitrodon If the result is not an integer, the fractional part is discarded.

Comment: Your latest edit forbids the sample input `2 * (3 + 4)` and doesn't capture the order of operations in `1 + 2 * 3`.  If you intend to capture order of operations in the grammar, you would need to split `arithmetic-expression` into three distinct non-terminals.

Comment: @Nitrodon Made a quick fix for now. I will work on it later on.

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5839/58563)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>427</s>  417 bytes

```javascript
s=>[...(a=s.match(/\d+|./g),o=[],d="+-/<>[]./",Buffer("kla`XslY`^KfMflY[`d^[jY`^jYa^ZeaXedfmY`f`t[[KfdM[CdtkqkqSMDsldd@@@@@[[MDd`iK^]kadX[fdD[Y^s@@@@MD@@XfMCtddM[[`dtkq[sk_V").map(c=>d+=d[c&7]+d[c/8&7]),g=S=>!(s=a.shift())|s==')'?o=[...o,...S]:g(S,s<')'?g([]):1/s?o.push(s):(h=_=>/u|[+-][*/]/.test(S[0]+s)?S.unshift(s):h(o.push(S.shift())))()))([]),'<'].map(s=>1/s?">"+"+".repeat(s):d.split`/`[d.indexOf(s)+3]).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVBRj9MwDP4t9IElS5fADQmYlm7i9jZVPFRCKya9RE3Sdu21vbk78bD/PtIDkUi2Y/v7/Dln82qwvDTjtOoH6@5e3lEmwDknRiJ/NlNZE/HLshsXFY0HCSq2MmIrsU1AcRHF367euwuJ2s7oE3a5Lo4@9V0O2hZwDs9zboqfzpyc9c@59noCOHqbwqOd2pf2JUsP2Fm7nw9AerC6ORaqNfYE3h4gL3CupIf9/uTTx8kGZKAOUMD26UdEg8aRlDKxTFoo339WLDjxJQQ0rmQmk3cEpeFYN34ilN5QygVd7MImYckhDiZTm4pkMW7nfEVA0c1HgbuBj1esCdINqeWTTMT1BmylYCmU4JPDiWTwQTGku4xf@7/8obkm/4DZ/5mUzmYmjhfbhXpTHH55HhIlEQuXX9zozBvechy7ZtJCg@VNb93v7z7k2VpRfh6aXut7OfQ4dI53Q0U8iR6W5IGtl5/o6qtYR5Te/wA)

[Try the Brainfuck code online!](https://tio.run/##jY5LCoIxDIQPFOIJhrlIyEIFQQQXguevk@Qv4s7Slry@mVxe5/vz9r4@1qLZ3H6GYDgVA6kIxgS8wmTlUIVVw27@DbR@H46RMP1qMgaUTE@2wA8ttePBOxUqTL2vqqG3KhGjB2q8C6zlkJzAIYvcTM0PvLfndm7rw1sE4oRc6wM)

This is using the BF code provided in the challenge and [the division algorithm suggested by Nitrodon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/239625/translate-an-arithmetic-expression-to-brainfuck#comment541448_239637).

#### Brainfuck compression

The BF code snippets are joined together with `/`'s. The resulting string is compressed by turning each pair of character codes \$(a,b)\$ into a single character of ASCII code \$N\in[64\dots 116]\$:

$$N=a+8b+64$$

where \$a\$ and \$b\$ are computed according to the following table:

```
+ - / < > [ ] .
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Hence the decompression code:

```javascript
d = "+-/<>[]./"
Buffer("... compressed data ...")
.map(c => d += d[c & 7] + d[c / 8 & 7])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBjoIwFEX3fMULC4UQYTmzGAxRdqQrE0PnhU4bXmugVdB2/H1E7@qe3Jw7qqfy/WOYw@42kV4WghLibFf87LHLizg6/BujH0lsnZKtd1yKxjDjOEoSOK44ciV@tWo1mSuXRgbExhDDIwV7t/cTq70jqt5BZDXJoRGdVdSioRq58O@F1VXVGnYMtJrr9aqit3/nOI3yq5qTHso9EGQlEPawga8Osk8t4PuDaRT1081PTuduuiSU@9kNIdkW2zRdlhc)

#### Infix to postfix conversion

```javascript
s => (                        // s = infix expression, as a string
  a = s.match(/\d+|./g),      // a[] = s split into numbers and operators
                              //       (including parentheses)
  o = [],                     // o[] = postfix output, as a list
  g =                         // g is a recursive function taking
  S =>                        // an operator stack S[]
  !(s = a.shift()) |          // s = next entry extracted from a[]
  s == ')' ?                  // if s is undefined or ')':
    o = [...o, ...S]          //   append S[] to o[]
  :                           // else:
    g(                        //   recursive call:
      S,                      //     pass S[] unchanged
      s < ')' ?               //     if s is '(':
        g([])                 //       recursive call with an empty stack
      :                       //     else:
        1 / s ?               //       if s is a number:
          o.push(s)           //         push it in o[]
        :                     //       else (s is an operator):
          ( h = _ =>          //         helper function:
            /u|[+-][*/]/      //           if S[0] is undefined or S[0] is
            .test(S[0] + s) ? //           '+' or '-' and s is '*' or '/':
              S.unshift(s)    //             insert s at the beginning of S[]
            :                 //           else:
              h(              //             recursive call:
                o.push(       //               extract the first entry of S[]
                  S.shift()   //               and push it in o[]
                )             //
              )               //             end of recursive call
          )()                 //         initial call to h()
    )                         //   end of recursive call
)([])                         // initial call to g()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTLkpswELz7KyZ7QfIDkt1cQsXxR3AkVEoLApTFEiWJjbdq/90ZAX5gHjq4XEjT09M9M3/ZOzOpFrXdSZXxcw77s4H9LyAwc4IA8AEImYsT8FOtuTFCyS0wAwyM1UIWK8C/ezD@kdm0JMHvbPPpBwXdXiFYnLgHYOpKWASzCmRzfOUaQWQGquaaWaXNChYPInWHCJlWTYa5oWaaS1tyww3FcIV54mQ7F65aIrUy1tWjGls3tq@lEsYiQIH3C/kLEO6x5mmjjXjnkDcytagIWPbWaRE5QecRmLzWi/qx9A2iOMGwL8QJzXxTitwSSuFz5ILkJwtYrf5AK6xmqeUZ5FodncAIgW/24FEPDpOZRY4vkH4jM54LibFIAZ@Hreytcr7vqy3gb5Q8yM7qmqNVyBXQPdXmC5e94pXhHXZBFi29qZmyqgr7Loi2i11QM2NaOmhAyWTBsz7OwM9JEfq4iwoe8cJrvxUkTuh8vw0Jwj9hS@cjP9b2ozOxRwqXO/emiDvfwNl6mEt6Icr6WQnvpkP5dWNKYuhUIGqDl9BOWu/UErtrnGMHpMt5a1J6n5dAiW3yZ9Dhd3lLXmHUdSbCwTwHzWe82SXxOkiCUWRbbhR/TUYN2n8cQPmWG0vamw2gCIchlLfx2tbeee166exed98CL3zYMpHfyG7oOjkHUMhLGq4tgjALuGfglRdCSrd6VN6P7u2E8@qO/e81IwsBc7Mx6oTpYLjsiZZ5LrS57I8J7hc1@gU0hebUnOmty6EPxayWrkcp3IpBasOi7yAooUsKCymsYFU3pbimSkJXU1kfgqez0smdcL9PH7IVhJ5TJY2quF@pguTk6XlNnjcv6@909yN4eaL0/B8)

#### Brainfuck output

```javascript
o =>                          // o[] = postfix list
[...o, '<']                   // append a '<' to trigger the 'print'
.map(s =>                     // for each entry s:
  1 / s ?                     //   if s is a number:
    ">" +                     //     append a '>'
    "+".repeat(s)             //     followed by '+' repeated s times
  :                           //   else:
    d.split`/`[               //     split the BF code snippets
      d.indexOf(s) + 3        //     and append the relevant one
    ]                         //
).join``                      // end of map(); join everything
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJRb9owGHzPrzjlYSFLSbR10rZSGGrRXlC0h0kTzAqLi20wGDuNXVZ@PbPJVE0T1A8nf/q@O9/Z3tA9tctWNq6vDeNHhiHirF/cjkiVF/EgunsSgre9eKtoPbNqXi@mohRqTmq2IBtfbuZ08ZPTGWdiN69F7QiZClaSe@a2j9vH7@XEKsbGYRFSTlgtp4tqS9mMCDYh84UNnXIyHs9Eee@YZ3ppTyV2@@tHnEb5jja9JYYjMGRDMLLEG3yskJ22BT6dynQQRQLDowmDF1dRwJDKR2yMdUI@Q0nrIpLnublCcptU5zm0abhmoGEEzsC1crXiLdyaI2laqV3S2bSXTvciwrTgdLkG1649wN5EwDvv3@LLJQoghe9L64/WT7sH3gYSEI9iH/8iCf8YHiUdI4vzljecup5NzzGEUcr85gwPByRZgm7Y1xZO7rj1Kjd49WIBrizvDLLcNkq6uqjJeYOn9un@7r5i6T8erJbetLNRN8dyqRl//iaC3wzX/wcM6bqQQaTliu@pdjCanwSqV5xGab4xUtf1xShB1giEF00HCMPge94e3Frq1XFptDWK58qseqJHkLxPrv7CdYAPAd4GyF52n1@6RYB@gipNj38A)

Comment: It's been I while I've posted this challenge, and your program is the only one with correct output, also with a clever compression approach. I see that some people click the green check for his/her favorite answer, and some people just leave it as is. Will it be okay for you to leave the answer unticked for future challengers?

Comment: @xiver77 Not accepting any answer is fine. Also, we've recently decided to [unpin the accepted answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23854/58563) on Code Golf because it doesn't make much sense on our site.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 675 bytes

```python
import shlex
s,b,o=[],'',{'+':'[-<+>]<','-':'[-<->]<','*':'<[>[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]<<-]>[-]>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<','/':'[->>>+<<<]<[->+>>+>-[<-]<[<<[->>>+<<<]>>>>+<<-<]<<]>>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<[-]<<[-]<[-]<'}
for c in list(shlex.shlex(input())):
 try:
  b+='>'+'+'*int(c)
 except:
  if c=='(':s+='('
  elif c==')':
   t=s.pop()
   while t!='(':b+=o[t];t=s.pop()
  else:
   while len(s)>0 and s[-1]!='('and c in'+-':b+=o[s.pop()]
   s+=c
for c in range(len(s)):b+=o[s.pop()]
print(b+'>>++++++++++<<[->+>-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<<]>>[-]>>>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]>>[>++++++[-<++++++++>]<.<<+>+>[-]]<[<[->-<]++++++[->++++++++<]>.[-]]<<++++++[-<++++++++>]<.[-]<<[-<+>]<')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLbboMwDH3nK7KnJA2h2zppEjP5kSgPLUtXJAYIMq3VtG9ndkIvmrYITI5zzgHbDKdw6LvNPDfvQz8GNh1af8ymfJf3lXU55/kXV7zkVoMyDnjOdUI6oRUisMZqo4wCcGYhgqatM4QBM4ZyJFhHOWJkg4MoxEtbVIAFuJ6ZtNHISiB5JTfyQ3@IgW7@ne37kdWs6VjbTEHESooYRdMNH0FIKcuMhfGEke1UxQ2Wpviq6YKoZcb8sfZDoMNmz@qq4oKXk6IHpny7JCUnBgvVVAz9ICSBz0PTehbuogSdexvcyy3Dt5Mvr8zWd2KS5p5tu1c2Wf3gopQQFcCVXmwWB0dS/JT6WuO47d68SEbyF3kYqaSd4tjAy4LUa22p4TgclSYVUWwrxGlRp29EqPlfcR7xIqDjZSGhoEEpYtBcyQfcmXd5A1oUkQF/WiwTTr@enOfHldioJ7l@/gE)

**Example:**

Input: `(8 - 4 / 2) * 7 + 1`

Output:

```python
>++++++++>++++>++[->>>+<<<]<[->+>>+>-[<-]<[<<[->>>+<<<]>>>>+<<-<]<<]>>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<[-]<<[-]<[-]<[-<->]<>+++++++<[>[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]<<-]>[-]>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<>+[-<+>]<>>++++++++++<<[->+>-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<<]>>[-]>>>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]>>[>++++++[-<++++++++>]<.<<+>+>[-]]<[<[->-<]++++++[->++++++++<]>.[-]]<<++++++[-<++++++++>]<.[-]<<[-<+>]<
```

Output of brainfuck program: `43`

Comment: I finally put in a division algorithm, and be warned, it sucks.

Comment: Multiplication and division are traditionally evaluated left to right: `36 / 6 / 6` should be 1, not 36.  (Also, [division can be shorter](https://tio.run/##dY9BCkIxEEP3nsL9MB9cuBtykWEWKggiuBD@@fuTtoqIBkppmpdpz8/T7XFdL/fm6RIsCvvjYQcza5GQkwAKmR7G3XgIyYs@zaAtL32sBsFTQYuIZ@eQ9t3CeSxR1QdE5j9RI58T0PUUA4teY0rwMb0n6pV7T2DF0hPxs0KfiDE12gY).)

Comment: What is `shlex` used for? If it just for removing spaces, there's shorter ways to do so. If it is neccesary though, you can omit the `input()` part

Comment: @xiver77 I'll change it. It may take me a moment though.

Comment: @JoKing `shlex` is used for parsing the expression into the atomic units. For example `shlex.shlex('1+(34*3)')` evaluates to `['1', '(', '34', '*', '3', ')']`. This makes translating the expression significantly easier.

Comment: @Nitrodon Does that division algorithm leave it's temps at zero? Edit: It looks like it does, but I'm making sure.

Comment: While I like your program is very simple and elegant, it still doesn't handle chained division correctly. `8/2/2/2` should be `1` for example, but your program's Brainfuck program outputs `4`. It would be good to place a note that the program has to be fixed.